# Python Pandas - absolute and filtering rows returning a boolean value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The code below keeps giving me a boolean output. My input values are positive and negative, and some zeros.
I would first like to convert all to absolute
Then get the rows that are more than 0, so I can do further processing.

Code below:

```
df[col] = df[col].abs() > 0
```

Comment: `df.loc[df[col].abs()>0]`

Comment: `df[col] = df[col].abs(); df = df[df[col] > 0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do:

```
df[col] = df[df[col].abs() > 0]
```